# How to generate the JSONSchema for the JAXB/Moxy annotated POJO class

Tags: java, json, jackson, jaxb, jsonschema

I know there are a lot of questions related to generating the `JSONSchema` from `JAXB` annotated classes using the `Jackson` but I could not find any example where JSONSchema generated using the `MOXY` annotated class.

All I want to know is how can I generate `JSONSchema` for my `MOXY` annotated class? As of now when I generate the `JSONSchema` for my `JAXB/Moxy` annotated class then I get only one field:

```
{
  "type" : "any"
}
```

Following is my class for which I would like to generate `JSONSchema` using the `Jackson` and `JAXB/Moxy` annotations: (As you can see I have `name` and `age` as mandatory field but they don't show up in the generated `JSONSchema`)

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
@XmlType(name = "Customer", propOrder = {"name", "age", "userExtensions"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Customer extends Person {

  @XmlElement(name = "name",required = true)
  private String name;

  @XmlElement(name = "name",required = true)
  private String age;

  @JsonSerialize(using = CustomExtensionsSerializer.class)
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TestAdapter.class)
  @XmlPath(".")
  @JsonValue
  private Map<String, Object> userExtensions = new HashMap<>();

  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setUserExtensions(String key, Object value) {
    userExtensions.put(key, value);
  }

  public Map<String, Object> getUserExtensions() {
    return userExtensions;
  }
}
```

Following is my `Main` class which generates the `JSONSchema`:

```
class JsonSchemaGenerator{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TypeFactory typeFactory = TypeFactory.defaultInstance();
    AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(typeFactory);
    objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().with(introspector);
    objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().with(introspector);

    //To force mapper to include JAXB annotated properties in Json schema
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
    SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
    objectMapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(objectMapper.constructType(Customer.class), visitor);

    JsonSchema inputSchema = visitor.finalSchema();
    String schemaString = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(inputSchema);

    System.out.println(schemaString);
  }
}
```

Comment: After trying a lot of things I found that it's due to the annotation `@JsonValue`. If I remove this then the `JSON Schema` is generated correctly. I want to know how to generate the `JSON Schema` with the `@JsonValue` annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the `@JsonValue` with my `Map<String,Object>` that's the reason I was getting just `type:any`. I removed it and then tried and it worked for me.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
@XmlType(name = "Customer", propOrder = {"name", "age", "userExtensions"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Customer extends Person {

  @XmlElement(name = "name",required = true)
  private String name;

  @XmlElement(name = "name",required = true)
  private String age;

  @JsonSerialize(using = CustomExtensionsSerializer.class)
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TestAdapter.class)
  @XmlPath(".")
  private Map<String, Object> userExtensions = new HashMap<>();

  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setUserExtensions(String key, Object value) {
    userExtensions.put(key, value);
  }

  public Map<String, Object> getUserExtensions() {
    return userExtensions;
  }
}
```

```
class JsonSchemaGenerator{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TypeFactory typeFactory = TypeFactory.defaultInstance();
    AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(typeFactory);
    objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().with(introspector);
    objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().with(introspector);

    //To force mapper to include JAXB annotated properties in Json schema
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
    SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
    objectMapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(objectMapper.constructType(Customer.class), visitor);

    JsonSchema inputSchema = visitor.finalSchema();
    String schemaString = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(inputSchema);

    System.out.println(schemaString);
  }

}
```